# regex to get filetype in url

Tags: php, regex

I am using a converter that accepts Regex to do a mass "search and replace" in a database to change all .png to .jpg.  Consider the following where a link to an image is mixed in with a lot of HTML code (simplified example):

bunch_of_text_http:// somewebsite.com/somepath/somefile.png_bunch_of_text

The "bunch_of_text" and "some-x" are all variables.

For clarification, the only .png's I need changed must follow a mostly prescribed URL.  For example, I need to replace all .png's on the example.com domain but not on other domains.  Here's another example:

Convert:
http://example.com/images/XX/YY/filename.png
to
http://example.com/images/XX/YY/filename.jpg

WHERE

XX and YY are variables and may be at any level of depth in the folder structure.

But ignore any other domain other than example.com.

The code on the backend is written in PHP.

I need one line of Regex code to return only the ".png" text so my script can replace that with ".jpg".  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might want to mention what language you're working in.

Comment: Sorry, the code is written in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url = "http://example.com/images/XX/YY/filename.png";
$result = preg_replace(';(http://example.com/images/.*?/.*?/.*?)\.png;', '$1.jpg', $url);
echo $result;
```

Some regular expression explanation: https://regex101.com/r/2ZDzq0/1

Note I've replaced the usual `/` delimiter with `;` because it's easier when working with URLs.

Comment: miken32, this helped me solve my problem.  Since I can't use the full code in my script (limited to only the actual RegEx code), I used the RegEx you wrote and modified it to solve my problem.  The code I used is:  (http:\/\/example\.com\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?)\.png and used $1.jpg as the substitution.

The full answer is here:  https://regex101.com/r/QIgKX9/1

Answer (score 0):

If literally all you want to return is ".png", then all you need is `\.png`.

That will match an instance of ".png".  You would then do a Find And Replace All operation:

```
Find All:   \.png
Replace:    \.jpg
```

If your question is more complicated than that (i.e. only return ".png" if its context is such-and-such), then please clarify your question.

Comment: Thanks, perhaps I should clarify.  The only .png's I need changed must follow a mostly prescribed URL.  For example, I need to replace all .png's on the example.com domain but not on other domains.  Here's another example:

Convert:
http://example.com/images/XX/YY/filename.png
to
http://example.com/images/XX/YY/filename.jpg

WHERE

XX and YY are variables and may be at any level of depth in the folder structure.

But ignore any other domain other than example.com.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:  https://regex101.com/r/QIgKX9/1

Thanks everyone!